# UnknownHostException while formatting HDFS

Tags: exception, hadoop, hdfs

I have installed CDH4 on CentOS 6.3 64-bit in Pseudo Distributed mode using the following [instructions](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Installing+CDH4+on+a+Single+Linux+Node+in+Pseudo-distributed+Mode#InstallingCDH4onaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudo-distributedMode-InstallingCDH4withMRv1onaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudodistributedmode). Everything is set to localhost in the Hadoop configuration files. But, still when I format the name node the below exception appears. When I add an `192.168.1.101 CentOSHost` entry to the `/etc/hosts` file the exception goes away and I am able to run format/start HDFS and run MR jobs.

I want to run MR jobs even when I am not connected to the network without adding an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file. How to get this done?

> 12/08/27 22:17:15 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine address of the host-falling back to "localhost" address
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: CentOSHost: CentOSHost
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostIPAddress(DNS.java:283)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.(DNS.java:59)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:1017)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:565)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:145)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:724)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1193)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some where the configuration is returning/ using the hostname as `CentOSHost`.

What does `hostname --fqdn` returns to you?

For Hadoop, it is important that name look-up and reverse look-up work successfully. You should be able to resolve the ip-address and resolve hostname from the ip-address (Reverse resolution). This can be tested using the above command.

The entry to /etc/hosts is required for the reverse resolution to work. Unless the entry and the configuration are pointing to localhost. Even in that case the `hostname --fqdn` should return as `localhost`.