# UnknownHostException - Formatting HDFS on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, hadoop

I'm attempting to run Hadoop 2.3 in pseudo-distributed mode on a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.9. I'm seeing the following error:

```
14/04/09 15:05:43 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine address of the host-falling back to "localhost" address
java.net.UnknownHostException: crowlem8: crowlem8
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostIPAddress(DNS.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1325)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: crowlem8
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? I saw the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146439/unknownhostexception-while-formatting-hdfs) about UnknownHostExceptions while formatting HDFS on CentOS. Wasn't sure how to proceed based on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to add the following to /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost

in the above context was crowlem8